# Trying to create a new partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

My computer's hard disk is divided into four primary partitions:

1. System
2. C:
3. Recovery
4. HP tools and 80 GB unallocated diskspace.

I'm trying to create a new Partition so that I can save my personal data separately.
The problem is that I can't create another partition because I've reached the maximum number of primary partitions. I can't convert any of those partitions to logical ones either. I'm using Easeus, and the error it throws is "No enough free space around the current partition for conversion".

Comment: See if HP allows you to create recovery DVDs and then delete the recovery or other partition. If not, you can always image the drive/partitions using CloneZilla or similar programs and then repartition the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

MBR architecture is limited to four primary partitions and there's no way to get around this limitation. You have three options:

1. **Extend one of the existing partitions** with the unallocated space to increase it's size.
2. **Delete one of the existing partitions** and reformat it to use for
   personal storage (*not recommended if you want to keep OEM recovery
   options or tools*).
3. **Add a second hard drive** for personal storage.
4. **Convert the drive to a GPT partition-scheme**. This would allow up to
   128 primary partitions, but would require you format the entire
   drive first. You would need a tool to back up your data before doing
   this. More info here:
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671.aspx

Comment: PC architecture is not limited, the MBR partitioning scheme is. GPT allows for 128 "primary" partitions.

Comment: @Karan You are correct, I have no idea why I put "PC". Silly me. Updated my answer and included a conversion option.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but there's no other solution ? because i don't want to delete any of these partitions, and there's no need for a second hard drive, because i have enough free space !
Creating a logical Partitions seems to be a good  solution, but i didn't find the right way to do so ! :s